# Out of memory on render despite enough space avaible

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, linux, memory-management

I am trying to render a small scene using cycles on a cluster. The operating system is Linux and the Blender version is 3.1.3. The avaible GPU is an NVIDEA RTX 2080 TI and avaible ram 117 GB. Although the scene only requires 256 mb in memory it crashes when rendering the first frame. The error message reads

> Malloc returns null: len=134217728 in Cycles Alloc, total 58075672
> Error: run out of memory!

The error occurs both for CPU and GPU rendering.

I am looking for a way of fixing this error or at least diagnosing where the problem exactly lies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the question in order to clarify the problem. Kind regards

Comment: How do you know it requires only 256mb of memory? Many things in Blender have separated settings between the viewport and render for performance reasons. Maybe check what objects are disabled only and viewport and not in render, also check your modifiers if some are enabled in render only, especially your subdivide modifiers that can have different subdivision levels. You can also check your particles systems. Finally, you should probably also enable the Simplify panel in your render settings and drastically reduce the render options, just to check if it helps.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/optimizations/performance.html